# Python tkinter app requires a variable that doesn't exist at the moment

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

At the moment, I am trying to program a python application that tracks my consumed time on different projects. I also use the following modules: Sqlite3 and tkinter.

[APP-GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PpzI.png)

On the right side in the image you can see the list of my current example projects I would like to track. The issue I have right now is that I have to choose a project in the list in order to pass the variable to the `fetch_times` function that requests the corresponding times from the database. However, I need kind of a default variable that is activated before I get the chance to select a project in the list.

The code below defines at first the function to select a project in my list on the right side in the image. The other function is a loop that should print the requested data in the list on the left side.

```
def selected_project(event):
    global selected_project
    index = project_list.curselection()[0]
    selected_project = project_list.get(index)

def show_times(selected_project):
    for row in db.fetch_times(selected_project):
        times_list.insert(END, row)
```

The following code is part of a second python file that contains database functions.

```
def fetch_times(self, selected_project):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT date_day, start_time, stop_time FROM projects WHERE project_name=?",(selected_project,))
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return rows
```

I already tried to generate a default `selected_project` variable but then I got the error message that the "***function is already defined***". I also thought about to implement an IF-statement that checks if the variable exists but I am just not sure what the best solution is. This is my first post here so I hope this overview describes my problem well enough.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: At the start, set the variable to `None`, like `var=None` and then later check with `if`, like `if var: #do something`

Comment: "_I got the error message that the "function is already defined"._". The error is because your variable name and function name are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I got the error message that the "function is already defined"**

As Cool Cloud said:
You have a function named `selected_project` and a variable named `selected_project` too. Change your function name or variable name and it will be fixed.
You declared `selected_project` as a None but after that, you declared `selected_project` as a function. so `selected_project` is a function and it's not a value anymore, and you are trying to change your function name inside your function and it's impossible.